# Can I download PS3 game updates from my computer instead?

Tags: ps3, gran-turismo-5

So GT5 2.0 is out and it's all terribly exciting. However, my internet connection isn't very great and it has failed completing the 1GB download for the last 7 times. Given the lack of resumable downloads on that platform, can I download the update with a sensible client on a computer instead (one with Range: http header knowledge)?  Or is there some way to make downloading through the PS3 more successful?

Comment: Are you sure your internet is at fault? With everyone trying to download the GT5 update at once, the servers are understandably overloaded. I'd suggest simply trying again in a few days before resorting to proxy servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PS3 supports the configuration of a proxy server in the Network Configuration. It can be any HTTP proxy server. So you could try to run a simple proxy server on your computer, and point the PS3 to it. Then, the proxy should be able to resume the download if the connection breaks, assuming it is setup as a caching proxy server.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there's no way of doing this *for game updates* at the moment. You can [update your PS3 firmware](http://uk.playstation.com/system-software/) by downloading it onto a compatible USB stick but at the moment I can't find any official source regarding doing the same for game updates.

Hopefully this is something that will be added - just because your PS3 is not online, it doesn't mean you should be missing out on patches/updates/free DLC/whatever!

Comment: Thank you both. Sylvain gets the tick for being slightly more answery (-:

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Download PRIVOXY google how to use it in PS3 will make your PSN Downloads extremely fast

Comment: You may want to at least link to some of the mentioned guides, or better yet put the guide here. Also, this didn't discuss the fact that the proxy doesn't download at the computer then transfer to the PC, but uses a PC to tunnel (proxy) the traffic to get around some PS3 direct connect issues that slow traffic some.